# Underscore template is not rendered due to variable is not pass

Tags: underscore.js

I am using underscore tamplate want to render the tamplate if variable in underscore is not available.
For that i am using this statement.

```
                          <% if (<%=xyz%>) { %><td> $<%=xyz%></td><% }  %>
```

But it not works.I want to make sure that xyz is passed or not? otherwise display other things of tamplate.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to template a variable in when you are inside a `<%` block.  The following will do what you are trying to do:

```
<% if (xyz) { %>
    <td>$<%= xyz %></td>
<% } %>
```

Comment: As a side note, take a look at Lo-dash as a replacement for underscore.  It's an optimized version of underscore that is still completely compatible.